# Python regex match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a text in a file

```
In [44]: with open(path) as f:
   ....:     for line in f:
   ....:         matched = re.search('^PARTITION BY HASH',line)
   ....:         if matched is not None:
   ....:             print matched.group()
   ....:
```

The file contains lines like 
PARTITION BY HASH(SOME_THING);
And also some other lines among which there is 
SUBPARTITION BY HASH(SOME_THING) which shouldn't be matched

After the match i would like to delete that line.
But the print matched.group fails why ?

Comment: why `re` here? just do `if "PARTITION BY HASH" in line` or `if line.startswith("PARTITION BY HASH"):`

Comment: Updated my question on why i should be using a regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this:

```
In [29]: strs1="PARTITION BY HASH(SOME_THING)"

In [30]: strs2="SUBPARTITION BY HASH(SOME_THING)"

In [31]: bool(re.match(r"^PARTITION BY HASH",strs1))
Out[31]: True

In [32]: bool(re.match(r"^PARTITION BY HASH",strs2))
Out[32]: False
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the print matched.group fails

Well it simply does what it is supposed to do: it returns the match. In this case since

```
>>> import re
>>> line = "PARTITION BY HASH(something)"
>>> re.search('^PARTITION BY HASH', line).group()
'PARTITION BY HASH'
```

If you want to print the lines that start with `'PARTITION BY HASH'`, based on what Ashwini Chaudhary suggested:

```
with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('PARTITION BY HASH'):
            print line,
```

Please note the comma to prevent print from inserting an additional end-of-line characters.

If you insist on using the package `re`

```
import re

with open(path) as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match('PARTITION BY HASH', line):
            print line,
```

Please note the usage of `re.match` without the starting position indicator `^` (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match for more information)